# Повесить enum на элемент combobox

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть VM со свойством типа `enum`.

Как вывести в `ComboBox` все значения из перечисления, так что бы выбранный элемент в `ComboBox` обновлял значение во ViewModel?

Comment: Вот именно ваш случай.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6145888/how-to-bind-an-enum-to-a-combobox-control-in-wpf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Допустим, у меня есть такой `enum` Этап:

```
enum Stage
{
    First, Second, Third, Fourth
}
```

и в VM свойство такого типа:

```
Stage stage;
public Stage Stage
{
    get => stage;
    set => Set(ref stage, value);
}
```

В представлении я могу привязать текущий элемент `ComboBox`а к этому свойству:

```
<ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding Stage}"
          ItemsSource="..."/>
```

остается как-то получить список всех значений Enum чтобы привязать их в ItemsSource. Я предлагаю сделать для этого небольшое расширение разметки:

```
class EnumExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    public Type EnumType { get; set; }
    public EnumExtension() { }
    public EnumExtension(Type enumType) => EnumType = enumType;
    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        => Enum.GetValues(EnumType);
}
```

Воспользуемся им:

```
ItemsSource="{c:Enum EnumType=c:Stage}"
```

или, благодаря наличию конструктора с параметром, еще короче:

```
ItemsSource="{c:Enum c:Stage}"
```

В принципе это уже работает, но в выпадающем списке выводятся строки First, Second и т.д., хочется привести их в нормальный человеческий вид.

Сделаем это с помощью конвертера:

```
class EnumToDescriptionConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public IDictionary Dict { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var key = value?.ToString();
        return Dict.Contains(key) ? Dict[key] : null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Dict.Cast<DictionaryEntry>().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Value == value).Key;
    }
}
```

В этот конвертер через свойство можно внедрить нужный словарь, например, в зависимости от текущего языка.

Ну и немного модифицируем EnumExtension, чтобы также использовался конвертер:

```
class EnumExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    public IValueConverter Converter { get; set; }
    public Type EnumType { get; set; }
    public EnumExtension() { }
    public EnumExtension(Type enumType) => EnumType = enumType;
    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        => Enum.GetValues(EnumType).Cast<ValueType>()
               .Select(t => Converter?.Convert(t, EnumType, null, Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture) ?? t);
}
```

Остается только завести в ресурсах словарь, который будет сопоставлять каждое значение вашего Enum со строковым описанием, и передать его параметром в конвертер:

```
<FrameworkElement.Resources>
    <col:Hashtable x:Key="Dict" xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
                   xmlns:col="clr-namespace:System.Collections;assembly=mscorlib">
        <s:String x:Key="First">Первый этап</s:String>
        <s:String x:Key="Second">Второй этап</s:String>
        <s:String x:Key="Third">Третий этап</s:String>
        <s:String x:Key="Fourth">Четвертый этап</s:String>
    </col:Hashtable>
    <c:EnumToDescriptionConverter x:Key="conv" Dict="{StaticResource Dict}"/>
</FrameworkElement.Resources>
```

Окончательная разметка вашего `ComboBox`а:

```
<ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding Stage, Converter={StaticResource conv}}"
          ItemsSource="{c:Enum c:Stage, Converter={StaticResource conv}}"/>
```