# Как передать значение во VM из RadioButton

Tags: wpf, mvvm

Есть 3 RadioButton

```
<RadioButton GroupName="Action" Content="УДАЛИТЬ" Height="40" IsChecked="True" />
<RadioButton GroupName="Action" Content="ПОЧИНИТЬ" Height="40" />
<RadioButton GroupName="Action" Content="ОТБЕЛИТЬ" Height="40" />
```

И есть во VM допустим свойство string action

Как передать во VM значение из Content, совсем запутался(( придерживаясь MVVM шаблона( не пойму как привязку сделать

Comment: Для MVVM удобнее ComboBox или ListBox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не должны передавать строку, у вас же ООП? Передавайте enum или класс, описывающий операцию.

Наиболее простым видится создание отдельной VM, описывающей выбор операции (код на C#):

```
class ActionVm : Vm
{
    bool remove;
    public bool Remove
    {
        get => remove;
        set => Set(ref remove, value);
    }

    bool repair;
    public bool Repair
    {
        get => repair;
        set => Set(ref repair, value);
    }

    bool whitening;
    public bool Whitening
    {
        get => whitening;
        set => Set(ref whitening, value);
    }

    public Action Action => Remove ? Action.Remove
                          : Repair ? Action.Repair
                          : Whitening ? Action.Whitening
                          : throw new NotSupportedException();
}

enum Action
{
    Remove, Repair, Whitening
}
```

В главной VM просто создайте экземпляр этого класса:

```
public ActionVm Action { get; } = new ActionVm { Remove = true };
```

Тогда разметка будет такой:

```
<StackPanel DataContext="{Binding Action}"
            d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=c:ActionVm}">
    <RadioButton Content="УДАЛИТЬ" IsChecked="{Binding Remove}" />
    <RadioButton Content="ПОЧИНИТЬ" IsChecked="{Binding Repair}" />
    <RadioButton Content="ОТБЕЛИТЬ" IsChecked="{Binding Whitening}" />
</StackPanel>
```

А в команду передайте параметр:

```
<Button Content="Выполнить" Command="{Binding OperationCommand}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding Action.Action}"/>
```

Или прямо в главной VM в коде команды используйте сразу `Action.Action`.

PS: использование ComboBox/ListBox вместо набора RadioButton позволило бы сделать это короче, без написания дополнительной VM (хотя там тоже есть нюансы с названиями операций, см. [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/827995/218063)).